# Return Flutter Value from function call

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, future

I have the following function call to a future that creates an item within Firebase, what I am looking to achieve is to return the document id after the item has been created. From what I have been able to achieve so far I can get the ID, but I am at a loss how to return this back to the widget that called it.
I should add that this function and the future are in 2 different files

Function

```
print("Task Details");
          Task task = Task(
            title: _title,
            desc: _desc,
            ownerId:
                Provider.of<UserData>(context, listen: false).currentUserId,
          );
          // Database update
          DatabaseService.createTask(task);
```

Future

```
static Future<void> createTask(Task task) async {
    await tasksRef
        .add({
          'title': task.title,
          'desc': task.desc,
          'budget': task.budget,
          'authorId': task.ownerId,
          'due': task.due,
          'location': task.location,
          'status': 'draft',
          'open': true,
          'timestamp': task.timestamp,
        })
        .then((value) => print("Task Added ${value.id}"))
        .catchError((error) => print("Failed to add task: $error"));
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not so much getting the ID, but the fact that it's an asynchronous operation. You can't return something **now** that hasn't been determined yet.

But since you already return a `Future` (which encapsulates something that hasn't necessarily happened yet), you can return a `Future<String>` to capture the document ID:

```
static Future<String> createTask(Task task) async {
  var docRef = await tasksRef
    .add({
      'title': task.title,
      'desc': task.desc,
      'budget': task.budget,
      'authorId': task.ownerId,
      'due': task.due,
      'location': task.location,
      'status': 'draft',
      'open': true,
      'timestamp': task.timestamp,
    });
  return docRef.id;
}
```

You can then `await` the call to `createTask`, or use a `then` block just as you did. So for example:

```
var newDocId = await DatabaseService.createTask(task);
```

If you want to show the new document ID in the UI, you can use a `FutureBuilder` in your widget tree to unwrap the `Future<String>` to  a `String`.